# how to handle lock screen button input for android activity?

Tags: android, lockscreen

Suppose I have something like an alarm activity which launches the alarm through the lock screen, accomplished via

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Now, from here I could press the back button to kill the activity, but I also want a press of the lock button to silence the alarm. How would I go about creating a handler for presses of the lock screen button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen to this [broadcast intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)

```
ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
```

You can switch off your alarm when you get this intent

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @DanielQuach: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346958/listening-for-action-screen-off-on-android - Here the response give a code to do that

Comment: That only works if the app is activity. You cannot listen for ACTION_SCREEN_OFF after your app has moved to the background. Reason being you must unregister the receiver in e.g onStop.