# Run service until device will be locked

Tags: android

I wanna run my service only when device is not locked.How exactly it has to work:

1. User runs the application.
2. Then service is run
3. Stop working when device is locked.
4. When user unlock device
       service runs again.

**I'm in need of help with first 3 points.** Because fourth point can be done with `ACTION_USER_PRESENT`. Help me please.

Answer (score 2):

1) You can start a `Service` by calling `startService(Intent)` from `onCreate()` or `onStart()` of your first `Activity` (alternatively, from `onCreate()` of your `Application` class).

2) Your `Service` is already running

3) To do so, you will need to detect the device lock event. The only approach I can think of here is listening for the `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`. You can find a detailed example in the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346958/listening-for-action-screen-off).

After you have detected the screen off action, you can stop your Service by calling `stopService(Intent)`

Comment: Hey. I've tried it ,so when I lock screen ACTION_SCREEN_OFF  begins to work but when I unlock it my service starts again. I assume this is happened because when I unlock device ACTION_SCREEN_ON begins to work.

Comment: @S.Drumble3 `when I unlock it my service starts again` - isn't that exactly what you were looking for? Or do you mean the service somehow starts twice on device unlock?