# Is it possible to determine the app has gone/appeared on the screen or not?

Tags: android

I want to determine if my app is on the screen or not, i.e. when user clicks the home button or locks screen I want to receive a one-time event that my app has gone into the background. And when user opens my app or unlocks screen I want to receive a one-time event that app has appeared on the screen.

**onPause**, **onResume**, **onStart**, **onStop** methods of the **Activity** is not what I'm looking. When the device screen is being locked/unlocked these methods are called multiple times. And sometimes when screen is unlocked and my app is on the screen I receive **onStop**/**onPause**. This is 
a bad scenario for my use case.
**onWindowFocusChanged** is called when the app opens any **Dialog**. This is also a bad scenario.

Is there another variant how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you are using AndroidX for your project, then you can use [ProcessLifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner.html) to determine the app has gone or appeared on the screen.

> **ProcessLifecycleOwner**
>
> Class that provides lifecycle for the whole application process.
>
> It is useful for use cases where you would like to react on your app
> coming to the foreground or going to the background and you don't need
> a milliseconds accuracy in receiving lifecycle events.

Using in your code:

1.Create a class that extends from Application class.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private final MyLifecycleObserver observer = new MyLifecycleObserver();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(observer);
    }

    class MyLifecycleObserver implements LifecycleObserver {

        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
        public void onAppMoveToForeground() {
            Log.d("MyLifecycleObserver", "My app moves to foreground.");
        }

        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
        public void onMoveAppToBackground() {
            Log.d("MyLifecycleObserver", "My app moves to background.");
        }
    }
}
```

2.Add `android:name=".MyApplication"` in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidx">

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Lock:

You can listen to broadcast intent `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`
[Listening for ACTION_SCREEN_OFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346958/listening-for-action-screen-off)

Home Button:

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint()
{
    Log.d("onUserLeaveHint","Home button pressed");
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
}
```

or use intent-filter

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

In an old application, I used to `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`

Here is an example

```
public class LifecycleHandler implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    private Context mContext;

    public LifecycleHandler(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    private int resumed;
    private int stopped;

    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }

    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
    }

    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        if (resumed == stopped) {
            //application is being foregrounded
        }
        ++resumed;
    }

    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    }

    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {
    }

    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
    }

    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
        ++stopped;
        if (resumed == stopped) {
            //application is being backgrounded
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I register it in my application object

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

        //...

        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new LifecycleHandler(this));

        //...
    }
```

And voilà !